# Precedence of 'or' and 'and' operators in C

Tags: c, logical-operators, ansi-c

In the following code, I am getting 10 | 1 | 1 as a result. But according to precedence rules shouldn't 'and' operator must be evaluated first?(and yield c=9) Like : d = a || (--b)&&(--c) since 'and' has higher precedence. ( or shortcutting breaks precedence rules ?)Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a,b,c,d;
    a =1;
    b = c = 10;
    d = a|| --b&&--c;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're writing the expression yourself, use parenthesis: `d = (a || (--b && --c));` or `d = ((a || --b) && --c);` and/or temporary variables: `tmp = --b && --c; d = a || tmp;`

Comment: First one yields the same result. The second one is correct. I know I can write it like that my question is why doesn't the first one gives the same result with the second one?

Comment: If `a` is *true*, in the 1st statement neither `--b` nor `--c` is evaluated and the value of the whole expression is *true*; in the 2nd statement `--b` is not evaluated, `--c` is evaluated determining the value of the whole expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence only determines which operands are grouped with which operators - it does not control the order in which expressions are evaluated.

In your example, it means the expression is parsed as

```
a || (––b && ––c)
```

Both `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation<sup>1</sup>.  Both introduce a sequence point (IOW, the left hand operand will be evaluated and all side effects will be applied before the right hand operand is evaluated).

Both operators *short-circuit* - if the left operand of `||` evaluates to non-zero, then the result of the expression is 1 (true) regardless of the value of the right operand, so the right operand isn’t evaluated at all.  If the left operand of `&&` is 0, then the result of the expression is 0 (false) regardless of the value of the right operand, so the right operand isn’t evaluated at all.

In your expression, `a` is evaluated first.  It has a non-zero value (1), so `––b && ––c` is not evaluated.

---

1. Along with the `?:` and comma operators.  All other operators (arithmetic, equality, subscript, etc.) do not force a particular order of evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

Precedence and order of evaluation are two different things. From [Logical OR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)
 documentation (emphasis mine):

> There is a **sequence point** after the evaluation of lhs. If the result of lhs compares unequal to zero, then rhs is not evaluated at all (so-called short-circuit evaluation).

In case of `exp1 || exp2`, `exp1` is always evaluated first as there is a sequence point after it and if `exp1` is non-zero then `exp2` is not evaluated.

Comment: Then, the compiler can't evaluate firstly, rhs which contains 'and' operator because of this sequence point? So if this is correct then the order of evaluation might effect precedence as it happens in this example?(or precedence stays same but the result of calculation is changed besides from precedence)

Comment: @Crazy_39365: `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation (unlike most operators in C).  Precedence *only* affects how operands are grouped with operators.